# why some vendors map Unicode characters to another character set(code page)?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading a book which talks about text encoding in .NET:

There are two categories of text encoding in .NET:

• Those that map Unicode characters to another character set

• Those that use standard Unicode encoding schemes

> The first category contains legacy encodings such as IBM’s EBCDIC and 8-bit char‐acter sets with extended characters in the upper-128 region that were popular prior to Unicode (identified by a code page). In the second category are UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32

I'm confused about the first one, code page part, I have read some questions on stackoverflow, none of them the same as the question I'm going to ask, my question is:

Why some vendors need to map Unicode characters to another character set? from my understanding on Unicode characters, Unicode can cover all characters of almost all language over the world, why reinvent the wheel to map Unicode characters to another character set? for example, line feed in unicode is `U+000A`, why would you want to map it to other character? just stick to the unicode standard, then you can use binary code to represent all kinds of character.

Comment: From your own quote "were popular prior to Unicode" - how is Unicode the answer if Unicode hadn't been invented yet?

Comment: I recommend reading Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: Addressing EBCDIC specifically, Wikipedia states that it was devised in 1963-1964. The Unicode article, on the other hand, states that "the origins of Unicode date to 1987". I haven't verified the references, but the IBM system would appear to predate Unicode by 24 years.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oh I thought unicode has been existed as a golden standard that many vendors have to follow. So you mean before Unicode was invented, IBM, Micrsoft etc they all have their own encoding scheme? A code point in one code page by IBM will not be the same character as the  same code point  by a code page of Microsoft??

Comment: @slowjams Yup. Before standards were invented, there were no standards. Welcome to the way of the world. Specifically the 1970s-80s had a lot of flux in terms of standardization, so it's entirely expected.

Comment: @Charlieface  Thanks for you answer. But why we need to map between unicode and old  code page, we wouldn't use a rare old 80s machine(if you can find one on ebay) to read the file create by the latest windows machine. The only sensible thing to me is we might need to use the latest windows machine to read those old files created by old machine manufactured in 80s, but if this is the case, the statment should really be "map to old character set(code pages) to  Unicode characters", but the author says vice versa  "map Unicode characters to another character set"?

Comment: This might be of interest: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/344491

Comment: There is enough code *still in use in Windows* that uses ANSI code pages